# Weird symbol in printf when using exponent notation

Tags: c, printf

I have come across a very bizarre situation. So bizarre in fact I'm not even sure how to ask my question!

I am working with a code that generates output file in simple format. The details of this format is not very important. What matters is somewhere in the file, there are several (tens of thousands of) lines, each with three pair of numbers separated by space and newline character, `\n`, at the end.

Each number is written using exponent notation, simply as:

```
fprintf(outFile,"%e %e %e\n",x,y,0.0);
```

where `x` and `y` are doubles.

Here's the strange part. In one of the files, with more than 100K+ lines or so, there is a line printed as this

```
7.812500e-02 -1.875000g+00 0.000000e+00
```

What on earth is **g+00** in `-1.875000g+00`?!

I have been using this code for more than 5 years, it has generated more than few tens of thousands of files, and this is a first time I have ever seen such a thing. I did a bit of online search but could not find anything?

Someone please save my sanity!

Comment: Cosmic rays, anybody?  Parity error — uncorrected?  The 2-bit in the character got tweaked between `e` and `g`.

Comment: `g` is a greedy exponent.  It is greedy because it ate all the numbers, leaving only zero :-)

Comment: Suggest backing up the harddrive and ordering a replacement

Answer (score 1):

That's a bug, the code doesn't show any possible case to display scientific notation with a "g", maybe the bug is being introduced by your data so I suggest examine that specific file, check for all the NP chars, etc. Then report a bug in the library.

https://sourceware.org/bugzilla